# BBM Android chat lost after Android crash

Tags: applications

I've recently been experiencing Android crashes (5.0), and the BBM app seems to be particularly volatile and could be the cause of the crashes.

I had a single contact and chat history with that contact, and both the contact and chat history have disappeared.  If I check the dedicated BBM folder on the device storage, the photos and documents from the chat are still there.

My question is: in BBM, if you delete a contact, will the opposing phone have both the contact and the chat deleted?  Or is this likely to be caused by a data-loss during the Android crash, and if so, where would I usually find chat history in order to investigate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the other user having an accident with their phone and losing their BBM contacts, which in turn deletes the chat.  I'm not entirely sure of the process, but they had to re-add me as a contact, and the chat remained lost.